# Android studio code autocomplete not working (Flutter)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, autocomplete

Recently I updated Android Studio along with Flutter and Dart plugins to the latest version. After this update, the autocomplete of Dart code stopped working.

I checked if the "Power Save Mode" was enabled, changed Flutter versions and also imported Android Studio settings from one of my workmates. Nothing worked.

Coding without the autocomplete is a waste of time.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS? Tried File -> invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: Mac OS Mojave (10.14.4). I will have to try the "invalidate caches and restart".

Comment: The "invalidate caches and restart" did not work.

Comment: ok, check if the sdk path is set to the right one in File->settings->languages and frameworks -> dart and for flutter. Other than that you might have to create a [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I just deleted the Plugin/Extension Folder from Visual Studio Code's Main Directory in C:/ Drive. What happened is that it deletes all the Extension files and folders created during the Installation of the the specified extension. Once you're done, re-install the extentions that you want to use. This method solved my problem. i hope this helps you too.

Comment: The question is about Android Studio not VSCode.